# global "class object" or global "server object"

Tags: c#

I am doing a project including a custom OPC Client.
The Class Main represents the MainWindow in a WPF application.
The private field `_opcServer` will hold an object for further use.
Only one `_opcServer` object is allowed at any time.
I came up with this (it's all sample code and works fine)

```
// "Main" Class --> it's a WPF Window
public class Main
{
// the "global" server object
private OpcServer _opcServer = new OpcServer();

public Main() {}

private void connectOpcServer()
{
    if(this._opcServer == null)
    {
        // the "global" server object
        this._opcServer = this.opcClientFactory().connectOpcServer("someOpcServer");

        if(this._opcServer != null)
        {
            // we made the connection
        }
        else
        {
            // connection failed
        }           
    }
}

private void disconnectOpcServer()
{
    if(this._opcServer != null)
    {           
        if(this.opcClientFactory().disconnectOpcServer(this._opcServer))
        {
            // disconnected
            this._opcServer = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
}

private OpcClient ocpClientFactory()
{
    OpcClient opcClient = new opcClient();
    return opcClient;
}
   }

// Client Class
public class OpcClient     
{
// the server object
private OpcServer _opcServer = new OpcServer(); 

public OpcClient() {}

public OpcServer connectOpcServer(string progID)
{
    bool madeConnection = this._opcServer.Connect(progID);

    if(madeConnection)
    {
        return this._opcServer;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public bool disconnectOpcServer(OpcServer opcServer)
{
    this._opcServer = opcServer;

    if(this._opcServer.disconnect())
    {
        this._opcServer = null;
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}       
  }
```

Not much comments in the code but I think you get the point.
Every time connect or disconnect is triggered via user action, a new object of the OPC Client is created and the Server Object is passed in the one or the other direction.
There will be more methods (like read tags, etc ...) like this, but since the user should use them only once or twice per day, I see no problem with creating new objects and passing something between them.

But what if there is a real funny user who thinks he has to use these things (connect/disconnect/ etc...) all the time. Then I will end up creating many objects!

I gave it a thought and came up with this.

```
public class Main
{
// the client object
private OpcClient _opcClient = OpcClient.Instance;

public Main(){}

private void connectOpcServer()
{
    if(this._opcClient.connectOpcServer("someOpcServer"))
    {
        // we made the connection and can now use 
        // this._opcClient.opcServer
    }
    else
    {
        // connection failed
    }
}

private void disconnectOpcServer()
{
    if(this._opcClient.disconnect())
    {
        // disconnected
    }
    else
    {
        // something went wrong
    }
}
 }

public class OpcClient
{
private static OpcClient _instance;

public static OpcClient Instance
{
    get
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new OpcClient();
        }           
        return _instance;
    }
}

private OpcClient()
{
    this.opcServer = new OpcServer();
}

public OpcServer opcServer
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public bool connectOpcServer(string progID)
{   
    return this.opcServer.Connect(progID);
}

public bool disconnectOpcServer()
{
    return this.opcServer.disconnect();
}

 }
```

Now I create a singelton of the OPC Client and pass it to the main class. Now only one object will be created, the user can click connect/disconnect all day long.

What is the best way to proceed here?

1. Store the Server Object in the main class
2. Store the Class Object in the main class
3. Depends
4. Both are bad ideas (if so, why? What can I do instead?)

Answer (score 0):

I am choosing the 2nd option.
By choosing the singleton approach I can make sure that there is only one Server Object.
This is very important.